# Zonal statistics for very large point layer with buffer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, big-data

I have a point layer and I need to calculate, for each point, the area of overlapping raster layer within 500m distance. This could be done fairly quick by generating a 500m-buffered vector layer from the point layer and performing a zonal statistics, for example like in this link:
https://www.perrygeo.com/zonal-stats-with-postgis-rasters-part-2.html

This works, and everything is fine except that I need to do this with about 50 million points…

Therefore, I can not handle a complete 500m buffered layer in memory due to the size, so I thought I would do something like this:

1. Select one of the points
2. Generate a 500m buffer for only that point
3. Calculate overlapping area with raster layer and for that buffer only, using a non-aggregate function.
4. Iterate from 1 for all points.

…but I have no idea on how to accomplish this in PostGIS. Somehow I need to avoid keeping the entire buffered vector layer in memory. Any suggestions on where to begin?

Comment: You'd run the same query as in that post - either with *aggregate* + `GROUP BY` or not - with `ST_Buffer(point.geom, 500)` in both `ST_SummaryStats[Agg]` and `ST_Intersects`. The buffer size is given in untis of CRS, so make sure your points are projected or use a cast to `GEOGRAPHY`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if that should do it. So, now I have this:


SELECT
    ((156.25*(ST_SummaryStatsAgg(ST_Clip(raster.rast, st_buffer(grid.geom, 500), true), 1, true)).count)/785375) AS percentage,
    grid.id AS id,
    grid.geom AS geometry
FROM
    raster as raster
INNER join grid on
    ST_INTERSECTS(st_buffer(grid.geom, 500), raster.rast)
GROUP BY
    id, geometry;


...but its not lightning fast unfortunately. Any additional suggestions on how to increase speed for large datasets would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty complex problem, but I think that inserting data into a separate table will avoid intermediate temp files and excessive memory consumption. Unlike select, where the whole resultset has to be temporarily stored somewhere before it is sent to the client. Also, make sure that you have spatial indexes in place for raster geoms. You can also divide your grid to chunks and run multiple queries, one for each chunk. That way you can utilize multiple CPUs...

Comment: But do not expect miracles if you want to analyze a whole world on your school laptop. That will probably not happen ;)